# How to change text color in footline

Tags: beamer, header-footer, color

I hope this is not a duplicate question, but I did not find my answer. I have seen how to change the background color of footline, but not how to change text color.

I have this code for my footline:

```
\makeatletter
\newdimen\mywidth%
\setlength{\mywidth}{\paperwidth}%
\addtolength{\mywidth}{-\beamer@sidebarwidth}%
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\beamer@sidebarwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{sidebar}%
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\mywidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{normal text}%
    \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\hfill\insertshortauthor{}\hspace*{2em}
    \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex}
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother
```

This code produces just what I want: Author and frame number in footline, but I want it to show the text in a specific color I have defined before:

```
\definecolor{beamer@ColorIPN}{RGB}{140,17,17}
```

My question is, how do I change text color in foot line from black to IPN color?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look about `beamercolorbox` in `beameruserguide` will see that its parameter is a `beamercolor`. Therefore, your footline uses `normal text` color to write text in it. As I image you don't want to change `normal text` definition, I'll explain how to change it for your footline text.

Once you have defined the color you want with

```
\definecolor{beamer@ColorIPN}{RGB}{140,17,17}
```

you need to use it in any `beamercolor`, let's say,

```
\setbeamercolor{myfootlinetext}{fg=beamer@ColorIPN}
```

With this command a new `beamercolor` called `myfootlinetext` is defined and it foreground component is fixed. Its background component is not defined.

Now you can use where you need it. In this case, replace `normal text` with `myfootlinetext` in the second `beamercolorbox`. That's all.

[image]

Following code uses `Berkeley` theme because your `footline` failed with default theme.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Berkeley}

\makeatletter

\definecolor{beamer@ColorIPN}{RGB}{140,17,17}
\setbeamercolor{myfootlinetext}{fg=beamer@ColorIPN}

\newdimen\mywidth%
\setlength{\mywidth}{\paperwidth}%
\addtolength{\mywidth}{-\beamer@sidebarwidth}%
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\beamer@sidebarwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{sidebar}%
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\mywidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{myfootlinetext}%
    \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\hfill\insertshortauthor{}\hspace*{2em}
    \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex}
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother

\author{I'm the author}
\title{}

\begin{document}
\section{First Section}
\begin{frame}{First frame}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It worked perfectly, just what I wanted. Best regards!